# Apparent weight of an empty balloon vs apparent weight of a balloon filled with air

Tags: fluid-dynamics, buoyancy, weight

If the same sensitive spring balance weighs (in air) a balloon when empty (W1) and when filled with air (W2), which reading will be greater and why?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this kids experiment a legitimate way to show that air has mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128468/)

Answer (score 2):

If the balloon is a rubber balloon, then when it is filled it will compress the air inside it.  The compressed air will have a greater density than the air outside, so the W2 weight will be greater than W1, the weight of the empty balloon.

If the balloon does not compress the air inside it, then W1 and W2 will be the same.